# Select rows from MySQL in the last 24 hours and skip rows based on interval X?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a trading bot and I use MySQL to import data and calculate technical indicators, I want to create a feature that allows me to import data more frequently and control the interval of how I select the data.

***Is there a query that will allow me to select data at a fixed interval in mysql?***

```
SELECT * FROM PriceHistory 
WHERE `RefrenceID`=1001
and `TimeStamp` > (SELECT max(`TimeStamp`) FROM PriceHistory) - 
Interval 1440 Minute
Group by `TimeStamp`;
```

Using this Query I am able to select price data for the Last 24 Hours. Is there a solution for me to select data in intervals of 5 minute, 10 minutes, 30 minutes etc?

`DataSet Example`

```
`TimeStamp`            `RefrenceID`

1. 2018-12-14 23:00:05   1001
2. 2018-12-14 23:05:10   1001
3. 2018-12-14 23:11:16   1001
4. 2018-12-14 23:16:21   1001
5. 2018-12-14 23:21:25   1001
6. 2018-12-14 23:26:30   1001
7. 2018-12-14 23:32:41   1001
8. 2018-12-14 23:37:46   1001
9. 2018-12-14 23:42:51   1001
10. 2018-12-14 23:47:51   1001
11. 2018-12-14 23:52:56  1001
```

I have thought of two possible solutions unfortunately I have yet figured out how to implement them.

1. add an auto-increment-id to my table, create a query that selects the rownumber. create a local variable `@rownum` and select all rows where @rownum = @rownum + (interval).
2. Select the first timestamp, create a local variables `@start_time`, `@offset`, `@count` then select min(`TimeStamp`)> @start_time + INTERVAL(`@offset` * `@count`)MINUTE

The issues I am facing by using an auto-increment ID solution is that I am tracking the price of 220 items in the same table (so sequential ids will not work) and therefore there may need to be a new index row created at the start of the query. The other issue I am facing is that my code is synchronous and therefore due to other running processes every import of data is between 5min - 5min 30sec.

thanks for your help!

best regards,

slurp

`Expected output:`

```
1. 2018-12-14 23:00:05   1001
3. 2018-12-14 23:11:16   1001
5. 2018-12-14 23:21:25   1001
7. 2018-12-14 23:32:41   1001
9. 2018-12-14 23:42:51   1001
11. 2018-12-14 23:52:56  1001
```

Comment: To make it clear, what would the expected result be, based on your example data?

Comment: I edited my question to fix timestamps and add expected output

Comment: This looks promising https://blog.timescale.com/time-series-data-why-and-how-to-use-a-relational-database-instead-of-nosql-d0cd6975e87c It's way more complex than your use case, but offers some ideas for how to solve some of the inherent problems

Comment: Not sure why the `10.` line is in the expected output. Its within the same 10 mins as `9.`

Comment: edited question to reflect error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using window functions (MySQL-8.0, MariaDB-10.2), we `DIV 600` to partition by the 10 minute (600 seconds) interval. We take the first in each group by id.

```
SELECT id, entrytime, RefrenceID
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
    id, entrytime, RefrenceID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RefrenceID,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(entrytime) DIV 600 ORDER BY id) AS `rank`
  FROM timedata 
  ORDER BY id 
) AS tmp 
WHERE tmp.`rank` = 1
ORDER BY id, entrytime;
```

Ref: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0c0cd5f8df35ed482955a49872de11f5)

Comment: thanks for the fast response! I am using mysql 5.7 which does not have ROW_NUMBER() function, I am attempting to recreate a workaround based on the mysql docs. 

I marked your answer as correct as I was able to reproduce your solution through dbfiddle

Comment: There's a general form in [this the second answer here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM PriceHistory 
WHERE 
    `RefrenceID`=1001
    AND `TimeStamp` > (SELECT max(`TimeStamp`) FROM PriceHistory) - Interval 1440 Minute
    AND substring_index(TimeStamp,':',1)%5=0
GROUP BY `TimeStamp`;
```